# How do I use vanilla JS to insert an mp4 video into an html document with specific dimensions, play it for 2 seconds, and then remove the node?

Tags: javascript, html, video, phaser-framework

As the title says, I need a way to insert an html5 video tag with a linked video, play the video for its duration (2 seconds) and immediately remove the video node when the time has elapsed.

My gut impulse is to do something nasty with a setTimeout... but I'm sure there's a more elegant way to do this.

Comment: You should be able to use the `ended` event to remove the video tag when the playback is over. What is your code so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The messy code I pulled together that is now working:

HTML:

```
<div id="really" style="width: 800px; height: 600px; position: absolute; background-color: #000000; z-index: -1;">
    <video id="yeah" width="800" autoplay>
        <source src="assets/intro.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
    <audio loop autoplay>
        <source src="assets/background.mp3">
    </audio>
    <ui-view></ui-view>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
window.setTimeout(function () {
    var parent = document.getElementById("really");
    var child = document.getElementById("yeah");
    parent.removeChild(child);
    //Do some things...
}, 3400);
```